# Error deploying grails portlet on liferay 6

Tags: grails, plugins, deployment, liferay, war

**I want to test a simple liferay portlet with grails.**

**I am using:** Liferay version liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2 that has tomcat version
   tomcat-7.0.27 embedded , Grails 2.1.0  , IDE  Groovy/Grails Tool Suite Version: 3.0.0.RELEASE  andJDK1.7.0_05

**I have instaled** plugins.portlets=0.9.2 and plugins.portlets-liferay=0.4

**After installing the grails plugins in a project i simply ran the following commands:** create-portlet directorio.testLiferay and generate-portlet-views directorio.testLiferay

I have configurated Config.groovy following like http://grails.org/plugin/portlets-liferay

**My portlet class looks like follow:**

```
package directorio
```

import javax.portlet.*

class TestLiferayPortlet {

```
def title = 'Grails test'
def description = '''Portlet de pruebas.'''
def displayName = 'GrailsTest'
def supports = ['text/html':['view', 'edit', 'help']]

//uncomment to declare events support
//def events = [publish: ["event-1"], process: ["event-2"]]

//uncomment to declare public render parameter support
//def public_render_params = ["prp-1","prp-2"]

// DEFINITIONS FOR liferay-display.xml
def liferay_display_category = 'SCRD'

// DEFINITIONS FOR liferay-portlets.xml
def liferay_portlet_ajaxable = 'true'
def liferay_portlet_header_portlet_css = [
        '/css/protoFlow.css'
]
def liferay_portlet_header_portlet_javascript = [
        '/plugins/richui-0.5/js/flow/lib/prototype.js',
        '/plugins/richui-0.5/js/flow/lib/scriptaculous.js',
        '/plugins/richui-0.5/js/reflection/reflection.js',
        '/plugins/richui-0.5/js/flow/protoFlow.js'
]

def actionView = {
    //TODO Define action phase for 'view' portlet mode
    portletResponse.setRenderParameter("prp-1", "value-1");
}

def eventView = {
    //TODO Define event phase for 'view' portlet mode.
    def eventValue = portletRequest.event.value
}

def renderView = {
    //TODO Define render phase for 'view' portlet mode.
    //Return the map of the variables bound to the view,
    //in this case view.gsp if it exists or render.gsp if not
    ['mykey':'myvalue']
}

def resourceView = {
    //TODO define resource phase for 'view' portlet mode.
    //Render HTML as response
    render {
        html {
            head()
            body {
                "Render me!!"
            }
        }
    }
}

def actionEdit = {
    //TODO Define action phase for 'edit' portlet mode
    portletResponse.setEvent("event-1","event-1")
    portletResponse.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW)
}

def renderHelp = {
    //TODO Define render phase for 'help' portlet mode
    //Return the map of the variables bound to the view,
    //in this case help.gsp if it exists or render.gsp if not
    ['mykey':'myvalue']
}

def doResource = {
    //TODO Define handling for default resource URL handling method, independent of porlet mode
    //Return the map of the variables bound to the view,
    //in this case resource.gsp
    ['mykey':'myvalue']
}

//invoked by setting 'action' param in resourceURL (as an example) to 'doSomethingAjaxy'
def doSomethingAjaxy =  {
    //render JSON
    render(contentType:"text/json") {
        example(mykey:"myvalue")
    }
}

//invoked by setting 'action' param in eventURL (as an example) to 'handleThisEvent'
def handleThisEvent =  {
    //render thisEvent.gsp
    render(view:"thisEvent")
}
```

}

If i execute run-app and war, it works fine. However when i put the war into deploy liferay directory and startup tomcat, i get error:

```
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
18:44:16,665 ERROR [GrailsDispatcherPortlet:276] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.container.AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.getInstance(AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.initPortletContainerAdapter(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.setPortletContext(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:116)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.init(InvokerPortletImpl.java:256)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.init(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.create(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.create(PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:310)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortlet(PortletHotDeployListener.java:546)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:321)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:120)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:151)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:141)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1621)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
18:44:16,667 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][PortletBagFactory:313] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.container.AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.getInstance(AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.initPortletContainerAdapter(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.setPortletContext(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:116)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.init(InvokerPortletImpl.java:256)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.init(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.create(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.create(PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:310)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortlet(PortletHotDeployListener.java:546)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:321)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:120)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:151)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:141)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1621)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
18:44:16,668 INFO  [GrailsDispatcherPortlet:98] Initializing portlet 'TestLiferay'
18:44:16,671 INFO  [GrailsDispatcherPortlet:263] FrameworkPortlet 'TestLiferay': initialization started
18:44:16,672 ERROR [GrailsDispatcherPortlet:276] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.container.AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.getInstance(AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.initPortletContainerAdapter(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.setPortletContext(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:116)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.init(InvokerPortletImpl.java:256)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.init(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.create(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.create(PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortletApp(PortletHotDeployListener.java:598)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:328)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:120)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:151)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:141)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1621)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
18:44:16,673 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][HotDeployImpl:191] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for testLiferayPortlet-0.1
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for testLiferayPortlet-0.1
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:151)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:141)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1621)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.container.AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.getInstance(AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.initPortletContainerAdapter(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.setPortletContext(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:116)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.init(InvokerPortletImpl.java:256)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.init(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.create(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.create(PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortletApp(PortletHotDeployListener.java:598)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:328)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:120)
    ... 24 more
```

I really apreciate any help.

Many tx.

Comment: I used Liferay 6.0.6 with Grails 1.3.7 to implement this portal: https://developers.t-mobile.pl
It worked fine (ans still works). Now I've tried your config and also got the same Exception. I see that for some reason Spring's ApplicationContextAware interface is ignored and LiferayPortletContainerAdapter receives no Spring application context upon init. So this is the reason, have no more time for investigation about the solution though.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in liferay 6.1.1

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29103

It appears hot deployment rearranges the listeners in web.xml when it merges it.
Might be better to stick with 6.1.0, or manually fix the web.xml everytime you redeploy

Answer (score 0):

Add `compile 'javax.portlet:portlet-api:2.0'` in your dependencies of `BuildConfig.groovy`

:D